# Heroku Connecting To database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on Shopify App in ruby on rails deployed on heroku. i have created a new table named homes in database using PostgreSQL Maestro Tool. It is also showing me the table count 1 in heroku databases dashboard under my database.

I have created a new model named Home
now i am trying to use

```
@home=Home.all
```

But this is returning nill to me.

Comment: I've never used the Maestro Tool but you're calling an ActiveRecord query (`Home.all`), so did you also run an active record migration?

Comment: No i am not doing that. Can you please tell how to perform that

Comment: Use [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)